# click function not working as expected on dynamically created elements Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have list of dynamic created elements which when clicked fires a ajax request and displays the result. The problem is it works only when it is clicked twice. The first click on element doesn't work. Whereas the second click works perfectly. I don't understand the reason behind this. I did try `unbind()` but it didn't help

```
$("#profiles_name ul a").on('click',function(event){
        $.ajax({ 
  }
  });
  });.
```

I did try `$("#profiles_name ul a").unbind().on('click',function(event)..` It didnt work still.

Here is my dynamically created tag

```
<ul>
  <a href="javascript:myfunction(this)" data-value="20/20"><li>Frontend Dev</li></a>
  <li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
```

Also to keep in note that, For example if i have two dynamically created list, When i click on list 1(first time) it doesnt work list 1( second time) works. After page refresh, 
click on list 1(first time) doesn't work and click on list 2 (first time) works. i.e First click doesnt work irrespective of the dynamically created element.

Comment: Yeah that never seems to work for me, try this instead: `$("#profiles_name ul").on('click', 'a',function(event){`

Comment: Nope it didnt workl

Comment: Show us a complete example then

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZNNej here is my code pen that has html and javascript function

Comment: [Here is proof it works](https://jsfiddle.net/nsn6aoxc/)

Comment: Check your console for errors! `"myfunction is not defined"` [This seems to work](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgRRMV)

Comment: that was for example , now changed in the codepen , I did do what you said , it didnt work still.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$("#profiles_name").on('click', 'ul a', function() {
    $.ajax({
        // Your code here
    });
});
```

> **Event delegation:**
>
> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Comment: No , It didnt work

Comment: Just keep in mind that performance can be effected by using `document`, all depends one how complex your situation is of course, most scenarios you wont notice any. Usually better to provide a more specific static element if you can. For example: `$("#profiles_name").on('click', 'ul a',function(event){`

Comment: @musefan You're absolutely right, I update my answer with your remark

Comment: @NaveenKumar Can you provide a better sample of your HTML/JS code so ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZNNej here is my code pen that has html and javascript function

Comment: @NaveenKumar It seems that it is an error with your `href="javascript:myfunction(this)"`, -> `Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined`

Comment: @GilleQ. that was for sample , you can see the codepen again , i changed it. There is no issue with it

Comment: @NaveenKumar Add jQuery to your codePen (Settings, javascript -> add jquery). The only error I got from you codePen is `GET http://s.codepen.io/profiles/20/20?_=1484656054639 404 (Not Found)`. I do not know what data you are trying to retrieve from your server

Comment: There is no problem with the server side or ajax. THe problem is in the frontend. I really dont understand this